# Sorting array algorithm - duplicate values

Tags: sorting, array-algorithms

I have an Integers array size N with duplicates values and I don't know the range of the values.
I have n/logn Different values in this array, and all the rest are duplicates.

Is there a way to sort it with Time complexity of O(n) and memory complexity of O(n/logn)?

Comment: yes, I think you can sort that array in O(n) under those conditions.  Is this homework?

Comment: @Andras
Yes. It's new for me and i'm a bit confused.

Comment: let's look at it step by step.  Sorting is an O(m log m) operation.  You have m = n/logn items, and O(m * log m) = O(n/logn * log(n/logn)) <= O(n), so we can sort the different values in O(n) time as long as we can do a duplicate check in <= O(logn) time (because that too would be O(n/logn * logn), which doubles the runtime but O(2n) = O(n)).  To detect duplicates in O(logn) you'd need some kind of balanced binary tree with O(logn) maintenance cost.  Or there may be a clever way of using a sort algorithm that keeps a sorted array while it progresses, then you can check in the array so far

Comment: Andras, this is not quite right. With a bbst, the duplicate check consumes O(n*log(n/log(n))) time. In my answer, I use a hash table to achieve expected O(n) time for the duplicate check.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=7;

    int v[]={4,1,2,3,2,4,1}; // initial array

    map<int,int>mp;
    vector<int>uni;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      if(++mp[v[i]]==1) // counting instance of unique values
        uni.push_back(v[i]); // unique value

    sort(uni.begin(),uni.end()); // sorting : O ((n / logn) * logn) = O(n)

    int cur=0;
    for(int i=0;i<uni.size();i++)
    {
        int cnt=mp[uni[i]];
        while(cnt)  // Adding duplicate values
        {
            v[cur++]=uni[i];
            cnt--;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // Printing final sorted array
      cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Here `uni` array keeps the unique values, that is maximum `n / logn` values.
Then we used stl `sort()` function having time complexity `O (n * logn)`
As here total element `n =  n / logn`. The complexity will be `O ((n / logn) * logn) = O(n)`.

So we see that, above method works with `O(n)` complexity with `O(n * logn)` memory.

Here `map<>` is used to count the number of times each distinct value appears.

Comment: updating mp[v[i]] could have an O(n^2) worst-case cost (if all hash keys collide).  The hash algorithm and data structure would also have to be specified to gaurantee O(logn) lookups and updates

Comment: How can you say O(n^2) for worst case ?
The complexity of lookup for map<> (sorted) is O(log N).
So complexity will be O(n * logn) maximum in worst case.

Comment: This is not quite right. With a bbst, the duplicate check consumes O(n*log(n/log(n))) time. In my answer, I use a hash table to achieve expected O(n) time for the duplicate check. As Andras mentions above, the worst case lookup/insertion for a hash table is O(n); however, they are typically used as though they are amortized O(1) time (i.e. they are typically used as though the hashing function is perfect).

Comment: @KevinL.Stern worst case lookup for map is O(logn). It uses binary search to search a value

Comment: Yes, but you are doing that lookup n times (for each element of the original array).  Since mp will only grow to size n/log(n) (because it only contains non-duplicates), that gives O(n*log(n/log(n))) for the duplicate check.

Comment: and i think OP asked about sorting algorithm to be O(n) and space O(n/logn)

Comment: OP asked about an algorithm for sorting an array of size n with n/log(n) unique elements in O(n) time and O(n/log(n)) space.  Your duplicate check alone consumes O(n*log(n/log(n))) time, which violates the O(n) requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep key value pair

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
int key = a[i];
//       if value is in map increase vale of this key
// else add key with value 1 
    }
```

now write this map data to output array using merge sort
hope this will solve your problem..

Comment: The question was for O(n) time complexity. With your process, it will go to O(n logn)

Answer (score -1):

Bubble sort takes O(n^2) time and needs virtually no memory to execute (other than to store the original array) - see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort . Quick sort is much quicker though - see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quick_Sort

Duplicates don't affect either of these algorithms

Comment: @robin
But bubble sort is O(n) in the good case. I need algorithm which is O(n) in the avarage case.

Answer (score -1):

Mergesort, e.g., is an O(n*lg(n)) time algorithm with O(n) space complexity.

You can use a hash map to extract the n/lg(n) unique items into their own array and note the number of times each item occurs; this is (expected) O(n) time and O(n/lg(n)) space.  Now, you can run Mergesort on the new array, which is:

O(x*lg(x)) time with x=n/lg(n) ==
O(n/lg(n) * lg(n/lg(n))) ==
O(n/lg(n) * [lg(n) - lg(lg(n))]) ==
O(n - n*lg(lg(n))/lg(n))
<= O(n) time

and

O(x) space with x=n/lg(n) ==
O(n/lg(n)) space

Finally, expand the ordered array into the final result by duplicating elements based upon the duplication number noted in the hash map.